# Why does my Android App crash when loading image from gallery the 2nd time?

Tags: android, image, gallery

I've written an app, thats loading images either using the android gallery app or by taking a photo using the cam.

When I now load an image using the gallery, everything is fine. When the code is being executed a second time (for loading another image), the application crashes.

```
            try {
            Uri data = intent.getData();
            ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
            Bitmap mBitmap = null;
            mBitmap = Media.getBitmap(cr, data);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        } catch(Exception e){
            showToast(this, "Failed loading image from gallery");
            return;
        }
```

The code crashes at the line `mBimap = Media.getBitmap(cr, data);`. Everything is initialized, there are no null values etc. The strange thing is: no exception is thrown, I don't get into the catch block to determine whats going wrong.

Does anyone have an idea about this? Am I not allowed to "re-use" the content resolver? Do I have to free it after the first usage or something like this?

Comment: Look into the `Log` class and put some debug statements inside your code block, there might be something else going on. If you are concerned with the `ContentResolver` try to set it to `null` first in your `try` block so it gets null before you load the second, but I don't think thats the case.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get `OutOfMemoryError` from the bitmap loading? If you are using big images, especially, if they aren't RGB_565, it's not that hard to go over the 16/24MB limit. The application can crash even if you HAVE enough memory left, but you can't allocate one big chunk at once.

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine the logs. There is most likely something in those logs that will indicate the source of your difficulty, even if there is no catchable exception.